# System of polynomial equations with cyclic symmetry

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

[image]

solve a system of equations with unknowns x1, x2, xn where n >=2

Answer (score 1):

Applying [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) we obtain that there are the obvious solutions 
$$
(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)=(-1,\ldots,-1),\; (x_1,\ldots ,x_n)=(2,\ldots,2),
$$ 
plus additional solutions given by $x_2=f(x_1),\ldots ,x_n=f_n(x_1)$ with polynomials $f_i\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of "high" degree, where $x_1$ has to satisfy another polynomial relation, i.e., is the root of a polynomial in one variable. For example, with $n=3$ we have that $x_1$ is a root of
$$
7168t^{24} - 96768t^{23} + 568512t^{22} - 1790784t^{21} + 2674128t^{
20} + 1157184t^{19} - 12720844t^{18} + 20363868t^{17} + 741015t^{16} - 47236372t^{
15} + 56887740t^{14} + 18319680t^{13} - 101773600t^{12} + 62822784t^{11} +
67667328t^{10} - 106537984t^9 + 3831552t^8 + 76778496t^7 - 35587072t^6 -
 28164096t^5 + 24330240t^4 + 4390912t^3 - 7667712t^2 + 1048576.
$$

Comment: So, How to Solve it?

Comment: For $n=3$ all solution are given by $(-1,-1,-1)$, $(2,2,2)$ and additional $24$ solutions $(x_1,f_1(x_1),f_2(x_2))$, where $x_1$ is one of the $24$ roots of  this polynomial.

Comment: The $24$ roots are all in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, e.g., $1.73486861698 + 0.923565826592i$, $1.73486861698 - 0.923565826592i$ etc.So there are only the two obvious real solutions.